# Create custom components in a for loop on init

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic

I am attempting to create all my components dynamically, based on what data comes back from a query, on Init

here is my helper.js code...

```
    ({
    getFeedback : function(component) {
        //do soql query in apex.

        var action = component.get("c.getFeedback");
        action.setCallback(this,function(actionResult){
            component.set("v.feedback", actionResult.getReturnValue());

           // render all the data in this component on return

             var feedObj = component.get("v.feedback");
                for(i=0;i<feedObj.length;i++){

           // finally create my components 

                 $A.createComponent("c:postcode",{
                                "object": feedObj[i],
                                "heading": feedObj[i].Name,
                                "mainText": feedObj[i].Feedback__c
                        },function(newCard){
                                if (component.isValid()) {
                                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                                        body.push(newCard);
                                        component.set("v.body", body);
                                        }
                        });
                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

just in case you need it heres my component

```
<aura:component controller="marksLightningClass" implements="force:appHostable" >
  <aura:attribute name="feedback" type="Kony_Feedback__c"/>
  <aura:handler name="changeFilter" event="c:filterFeedback" action="{!c.changeFilter}"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
            <c:navBar/>
            {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

Seems straight forward but it does not work for me,
Any thoughts?

Thank you for your time and brain :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark almost the same code seemed to work fine for me I did it with account object, following are the code snippets

Component1 :

```
<aura:component controller="ApexController" implements="force:appHostable" >
  <aura:attribute name="accountRecList" type="Account"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

Helper:

```
callApex : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAllAccounts");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.accountRecList", response.getReturnValue());
                var feedObj = component.get("v.accountRecList");
                for(var i=0; i<feedObj.length; i++){

                    $A.createComponent("c:dynamicComp",{
                        "Name": feedObj[i].Name,
                    },function(newCard){
                        if (component.isValid()) {
                            var body = component.get("v.body");
                            body.push(newCard);
                            component.set("v.body", body);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

dynamicComp :

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="Name" type="String"/>
    Account Name : {!v.Name} <br/>
</aura:component>
```

May be there is some problem with your 'postcode' code.

Comment: Thanks Gopal  I assumed my component was fine, as i can call it in Markup using <aura:iteration >  <c:postcard /> etc. I created a Much simpler component with the same code and does in fact work. ill have a look at my broken component now, Thankyou for your Help!

Comment: It was the component. deleted on offending line of code and voila! Works Thanks Again Gopal

Comment: Welcome mark @Mark, glad it helped